# Is it possible to catch a SIGINT in node child process, do some cleanup, and still exit with a SIGINT?

Tags: node.js

When a child process receives a SIGINT I want to do some cleanup. Afterwards I want to let the parent know the child exited with a SIGINT.

The first part is easy, but the second isn't as the following example illustrates. Any way to pass through the originally received signal?

```
process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  // Do some cleanup here

  process.exit() // No way to pass the the original signal "SIGINT!", since exit(<code>) only excepts 1 argument.
})

// Therefore, 'signal is never set here 
parent.child.on("exit", (code, signal) => {
  // signal is empty
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You can use the `process.kill()` method to send the `SIGINT` signal to the child process after the cleanup has completed.

The child process to exit with a `SIGINT` signal and you can then access the signal value in the parent process using the second argument of the `child_process.on('exit')` event.

As a summary, when the parent process receives a `SIGINT` signal, it will perform cleanup and then send a `SIGINT` signal to the child process using the `kill()` method.

The child process will then receive the `SIGINT` signal and exit with a status code of 0. The parent process can then access the signal value in the `exit` event listener.